# Is Sri Lanka Open and safe for travel?

Tags: indian-citizens, safety, sri-lanka

I am an Indian citizen, and I am planning to visit Sri Lanka in last week of December 2022. Has anybody recently travelled to Sri Lanka for tourism? How safe is it? Are all places open? How should I plan my travel?

Comment: It's open, and tourists are unlikely to be targeted, but the economic situation is going from bad to worse and street demonstrations are back: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/10/27/protests-in-sri-lanka-over-economic-crisis-and-police-brutality

Comment: @lambshaanxy, if you write this much, you should post as an answer.

Comment: @Willeke I was in Laos recently, which is also wracked by economic crisis if you believe the news, but on the ground everything was fine. So I'll let somebody with personal experience answer.

Comment: Check the answer in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177353/is-sri-lanka-still-a-viable-destination-for-a-relaxing-holiday-given-these-crier